# iptables counters in NAT table and state NOT NEW

Tags: iptables, nat, linux-networking, conntrack

I read everywhere that it is dangerous to do traffic filtering in the nat table because the nat table is only consulted for connections whose state is "NEW" (later packets bypass the table).

**Does it mean that nat table counters are only incremented for the first packet of every connection?**

Should I then use the chain PREROUTING of the table RAW if I need reliable traffic information?

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter (extract)]

Comment: What do you mean by 'reliable traffic information' ?

Comment: I need all of the traffic. Not only the traffic caused by the first packet of a connection. If I download 1Go with curl for example, the 1Go won't show up in the iptables counters in nat. Because only the TCP SYN (state NEW) will get through nat (about 60 bytes).

Comment: Could you add the iptables rule(s) which redirect traffic to the transparent proxy?

Answer (score 2):

If the server is a gateway - you should use FORWARD chain

Setup iptables

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 92.48.119.223 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -s 92.48.119.223 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

We will download a simple file

```
# curl -I http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/images/boot.iso
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 18:17:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 21:41:08 GMT
ETag: "2800ae-e600000-51c8324d84500"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 241172480
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Download the file

```
# wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/images/boot.iso
--2016-03-17 20:18:14--  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/images/boot.iso
Resolving mirror.centos.org (mirror.centos.org)... 92.48.119.223
Connecting to mirror.centos.org (mirror.centos.org)|92.48.119.223|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 241172480 (230M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `boot.iso'

100%[======================================================================>] 241,172,480 9.67M/s   in 25s

2016-03-17 20:18:39 (9.26 MB/s) - `boot.iso' saved [241172480/241172480]
```

Check the rules

```
# iptables -L FORWARD -n -v -x
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 408 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   33478  1756965 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            92.48.119.223       tcp dpt:80
   27818 244733384 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       92.48.119.223        0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80
```

244733384 is what you are looking for.

```
244733384 - 241172480 = 3560904 ~ 3,4 Mb
```

It's an overhead of tcp/ip + http

> Does it mean that nat table counters are only incremented for the first packet of every connection?

yes, it does. And then it uses connection tracking

```
# lsmod | grep conn
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9154  3 iptable_nat,nf_nat
nf_conntrack           79206  3 iptable_nat,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv4          1483  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

> The idea is to do it with iptables. Very lightweight (no proxy source code modification, and we let the kernel count packets instead of doing it ourself).

As you said before - you have 5-50 clients, so you can try do accounting through iptables and -j LOG action

Configure rsyslog

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/accounting.conf
:msg, contains, "CLIENT-192.168.88.87-IN" /var/log/accounting/client-192.168.88.87.log
:msg, contains, "CLIENT-192.168.88.87-OUT" /var/log/accounting/client-192.168.88.87.log
:msg, contains, "CLIENT"     ~
```

Configure iptables

```
# iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.88.87 ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j LOG --log-prefix "CLIENT-192.168.88.87-OUT "

# iptables -t mangle -I INPUT ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.88.87 -j LOG --log-prefix "CLIENT-192.168.88.87-IN "
```

Check that all works as it should

```
# ping -c 1 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=43.1 ms

--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 43ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 43.114/43.114/43.114/0.000 ms

# iptables -t mangle -L INPUT -nvx
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1256 packets, 116836 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       1       84 LOG        all  --  *      *      !192.168.0.0/16       192.168.88.87       LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `CLIENT-192.168.88.87-IN '

# iptables -t mangle -L OUTPUT -nvx
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 304 packets, 91325 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       1       84 LOG        all  --  *      *       192.168.88.87       !192.168.0.0/16      LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `CLIENT-192.168.88.87-OUT '

# cat /var/log/accounting/client-192.168.88.87.log
Mar 21 09:12:22 ci kernel: CLIENT-192.168.88.87-OUT IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.88.87 DST=8.8.4.4 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=38520 SEQ=1
Mar 21 09:12:22 ci kernel: CLIENT-192.168.88.87-IN IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:eb:c9:fc:4c:5e:0c:51:b7:d4:08:00 SRC=8.8.4.4 DST=192.168.88.87 LEN=84 TOS=0x04 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=38520 SEQ=1
```

Do some real test

```
# wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
--2016-03-21 09:14:35--  https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Resolving bitbucket.org... 104.192.143.2, 104.192.143.3, 104.192.143.1
Connecting to bitbucket.org|104.192.143.2|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
...
Resolving bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com... 54.231.49.250
Connecting to bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com|54.231.49.250|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 23415665 (22M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: “phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2”

100%[==============================================================================================>] 23,415,665  3.78M/s   in 6.7s

2016-03-21 09:14:43 (3.31 MB/s) - “phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2” saved [23415665/23415665]
```

As you can see from the output - the client has been downloaded ~ 22,33 Mb

```
23415665 (bytes) / 1024 (Kbytes) / 1024 (Mbytes) ~ 22,33 Mb
```

And now we can calculate through log file

```
# cat client-192.168.88.87.log | grep CLIENT-192.168.88.87-IN | grep SRC=54.231.49.250 | grep 'SPT=443' | awk '{print $12}' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk '{SUM+=$1;} END{printf "%.2f Mb",SUM/1048576}'
22.75 Mb
```

Of course you can mix and filter sport/dport/dest ip and so on and get any statistics you want

Comment: My question is not whether I have to use PREROUTING or FORWARD. Although this router is the gateway, I have to use PREROUTING in my case. I can't use FORWARD. This router isn't doing conventional routing. It's doing transparent proxying instead.

Comment: Are you using squid to do transparent proxying?

Comment: It's another program, but the reason I have to be in PREROUTING is because in my PREROUTING NAT table, there is a rule with target "REDIRECT", which transparently redirects all traffic to the proxy (local process on the router itself). So, if I plug my "traffic accounting" anywhere after PREROUTING (FORWARD or INPUT), it's too late, as no traffic will be seen there.

Comment: You can still use input/output chains of the filter table but you won't be able to determine the original ip address of the client. So with transparent proxying the only way to get client related information about traffic - only via proxy program itself. For example with squid you can use SAMS

Comment: The idea is to do it with iptables. Very lightweight (no proxy source code modification, and we let the kernel count packets instead of doing it ourself). I should be able to get the LAN output traffic (entering the proxy) in PREROUTING RAW or MANGLE (-i lan) and get the answers payload coming out of the proxy in one of the OUTPUT chains (except NAT). I should then have all needed information. IP, MAC address... How does it sound?

Comment: How many clients do you have?

Comment: Currently, most of the time it's between 3 and 50.